# Move font awesome fonts from bower using gulp task

Tags: gulp, bower, font-awesome

I am trying to move all the font-awesome fonts from the `bower_components` folder to my build directory, but the task isn't copying any files.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify');

var config = {
    bowerDir: 'bower_components'
}

gulp.task('fa', function() {
    return
        gulp.src(config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/fonts/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/fonts/font-awesome/'));
});
```

When I run `gulp fa` it runs fine, but no files appear in my `assets/fonts/font-awesome` directory.

I know the .pipe(gulp.dest()) function works because I have a scripts function like so:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src([
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js',
        'bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js',
        'assets/js/custom/app.js',
    ])
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
    .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Scripts minified'
    }));
});
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

My folder structure is like this:

```
assets/
--fonts/
----font-awesome/
gulpfile.js
bower_components/
--font-awesome/
----fonts/
------fontawesome-webfont.eot
------fontawesome-webfont.svg
------fontawesome-webfont.ttf
------fontawesome-webfont.woff
------fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

Comment: This is the exact code that I use
`gulp.task('icons', function() { 
    return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/**.*') 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts')); 
});` 
... and I can confirm it works fine. Maybe check for a typo or other mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest to use gulp-copy

```
var copy = require('gulp-copy');    

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src(['bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/*.*'])
        .pipe(copy('assets/fonts/font-awesome/', { prefix: 3}));

});
```

Comment: Just tried this. It has copied the 'bower_components/' folder structure into the build directory?

Comment: I added "prefix" option in my answer, It's working with your folder structure